# Counting the number of electrons in band in a 1D crystal

Tags: condensed-matter

I don't understand the following thing :

Imagine I have a 1D Bravais lattice of size N of parameter $a$ containing 1 atom at each node ($N_{atoms}=N$).

I will have N reciprocal vectors in my first brillouin zone.

Now I consider the ***same arrangement of atoms*** (it is the same physical problem) but I decide to take a 1D Bravais lattice of parameter $2a$. So it just a change of convention not a change of physical problem !!

I will have $N/2$ bravais nodes, so $N/2$ reciprocal vectors.

I have one electron and one orbital per atom and I want to know if I will fill all the bands.

If I reason using my first Bravais lattice, I will have $2N$ states available ($2$ is for the spin), and $N$ electrons => the band will not be filled.

If I reason using my second Bravais lattice, I will have $2*N/2$ states available and $N$ electrons => the band will be filled.

What did  I forget when I changed my Bravais lattice ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

By enlarging the unit cell, you break the translation symmetry, then more terms (which was originally forbidden by the translation symmetry) can now be added to the Hamiltonian. For example, if your unit cell contains two atoms, then the two atoms can be of different chemical elements and can have different chemical potentials. The staggered chemical potential is a new term that can appear in the Hamiltonian. With these new terms, the band structure is changed substantially. Typically a band gap will open at the new (smaller) Brillouin zone boundary. Then the original electronic band will split apart from the middle into two smaller bands. So if the original band is half-filled, the new band structure will have a fully-filled valence band and an empty conduction band. So what you have forgotten when you change the Bravais lattice is to add all possible terms to the Hamiltonian that is compatible with the new translation symmetry.

Comment: I am not sure to really understand. I have one atoms "A" per cell with a bravais lattice #1, I have a Brillouin zone that goes from -pi/a to pi/a.
If I change my lattice and put two atoms "A" per cell (but this is just a change of convention, my atoms are exaclty the same !!!!), my brillouin zone will be twice smaller with half state possible than in the original case.

In the second case I will have twice less state available than in the first. But it is the same physical problem.

So : how is it possible to fill the band in the second case ?

Comment: @user3183950 By definition, a **unit** cell is the *minimal unit* of repeating structure in a lattice. So you can not put two atoms "A" in a unit cell, otherwise, your unit cell is not "unit" (you could have defined a smaller unit cell). If you violate the definition of the unit cell, then all theorems regarding band counting will not apply. Because in the extreme limit, why don't you take the whole lattice as your "unit cell", then there is no band structure at all, and the whole discussion is meaningless.